# `apt-cache policy` lists repos not shown in `add-apt-repository --list`

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, add-apt-repository

I have several 3rd party repos in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`, including for apt "`foobaz`", which is installed.  I want to check which repository `foobaz` came from, or could come from:

figure out what package:

```
$ which foobaz
/usr/bin/foobaz

$ # FWIW - apt-file does not find anything for this, whereas dpkg-S does (and is limited to just my system, unlike apt-file afaict.
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/foobaz
foobaz
```

check which version would be preferred in an `upgrade`

```
$ sudo apt update
$ apt policy foobaz
 *** 3.1.0-1 500
        500 https://repo.foobaz.com/debian stable/main all Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.0.0-1 500
        500 https://repo.foobaz.com/debian stable/main all Packages
 ...
```

but, why is the `foobaz` repository not listed here?

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --list | grep foobaz
$ # nothing

$ ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ | grep foobaz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 161 Aug 11 16:52 foobaz-stable.list

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/foobaz-stable.list
deb [arch="all", signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/foobaz-stable-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.foobaz.com/debian stable main
```

`XY`: what command should I be using on ubuntu/debian to:

1. ascertain which repositories contain the given package (what I'm doing above - a question in it's own right)?
2. specifically,  tell me as quickly/easily (**and 100% robustly**) from what repository a given executable file on my box came?

Comment: Unable to reproduce: `add-apt-repository --list | grep foobaz` returns the foobaz source(s) as expected.

Comment: @user535733 - I'm not sure what to tell you.  Yes, this seems wrong to me.   Poking around - one interesting thing I see is that `add-apt-repository --list` displays **two of the four** entries I have in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.  However, given that `dpkg -S $(which foobaz)` finds the file in the `foobaz` package, can't we tell definitively that the currently installed program is coming from a `deb` (and in my case `apt` since I haven't installed anything via `dpkg -i` here)?  (note: edits for clarity)

Comment: "*given that dpkg -S $(which foobaz) finds the file in the foobaz package, can't we tell definitively that the currently installed program is coming from a deb*:" Yes, the output of `dpkg -S` is a definitive answer...as long as your package database is accurate (true 99% of the time).

Comment: "what repository a given executable file on my box came" this is, in the general case, impossible. Imagine: you installed a package X of version Y from some repo. For some reason, that repo removes package X. Another repo you had configured also has package X with version Y (not too odd if two independent groups package the same software). A long time has passed since you installed it, so your logs are gone as well, and your caches have been cleared. To all appearences, it will look as if X came from the second repo

Comment: @muru - I [think I] agree with you - but note in my case the version, timestamps, and critically `sha1sum` are all identical - *and* while memory is absoutely falliable, in the *recent* past (encompassing those `ctime`/`mtime`'s) I am confident I haven't done such a thing.  In a case that's general **within** constrained such as this, do you still feel it's impossible?

Comment: Still not possible in the general case - take a repo with, say, testing, stable and archive pocket which moves the same package around. Again, not 100% possible to guarantee it came from which pocket.

Comment: I suppose by the time I figure this out, my `framework-16` will arrive and I'll be upgrading everything to 22.04 or 24.04 :(