# understanding why a package is installing a file that `dpkg --search` & `dpkg --listfiles ...` don't know about?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I have installed a particular program via `apt`.  It originates from a 3rd party repo, and I have 100% confidence the file was installed & updated via `apt` not some other path (per data I list below)

I have stripped the specific package name because I would like to know (A) do I understand `dpkg --search` capabilities correctly, and (B) faced with an unknown-to-`dpkg` file, how do I definitively figure out where it came from?

```
$ which -a foobaz
/usr/bin/foobaz
/bin/foobaz
```

These^ are distinct but identical:

- files exist
- neither are symlinks (`test -L $file` fails) OR hardlinkes (`stat -c %h -- $file` prints `1`)
- have the same `ctime` and `mtime`

  - note the package has been updated recently, all the times^ look correct to me.
- have identical `sha1sum` hashes

but dpkg only seems to know about the first one?

```
$ dpkg --get-selections  | grep -i foobaz
foobaz              install

$ dpkg-query -S /usr/bin/foobaz 
foobaz: /usr/bin/foobaz
dpkg-query -S /bin/foobaz 
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /bin/foobaz
```

Shouldn't `dpkg -S <file>` always know about the files added by the debs/apt?  How should I approach this issue to determine where some 'unknown' file originated when I know *with high confidence* it was installed with `apt`?

Comment: *"These^ are distinct but identical"* likely `/bin` is symlinked to `/usr/bin` - see for example [why there is two identical bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408545/why-there-is-two-identical-bash)

Comment: @steeldriver - no, they are **not** symlinks, as I specify in my question.  `test -L` and `ls -al` ... unless I'm running those checks incorrectly.

Comment: It is not the **files** that are symbolicly linked, it's the parent **directories** (look at the output of `ls -ld /bin`)

Comment: `dpkg -S /path/to/foobaz` will indeed know about any installed packages that provide that file. However, that number of packages is usually 1. More than one package that provides the same file must be accounted for in the control file, or apt will throw a terminating error: "*Package X is attempting to overwrite File A, which is also provided by already-installed Package Y*." Debian worked all this out over 20 years ago.

Comment: Oh, OK @steeldriver, that would make sense.  It would seem this is a red-herring then (I was stumped by this while poking around trying to understand https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483131/apt-cache-policy-lists-repos-not-shown-in-add-apt-repository-list?noredirect=1#comment2596954_1483131).  If you add this as an answer I'll accept.  If possible, please include any hints on how this would be easy to figure out in the general case - now that you point it out, `/bin -> usr/bin/` is somewhat obvious, but is there a way to ask in `bash` "do these files resolve to the same inode|blocks|etc?

Comment: now seeing the **root** cause, I do agree that the root cause is shared with the "duplicates" linked - however, I'm this is not terribly helpful behavior to mark this as duplicate - the best way I can think to explain my viewpoint is an example: closing as Dup is the same as shutting down a student asking about some cellular traits they observe in lympphocytes, because the same phenomenon was explained elsewhere using erythrocytes as an example.  Same root cause?  Yes, absolutely.  Same **question**?  Not really, and certainly not from the perspective of the next person searching!

Comment: @somebitsflipped that's the entire point of duplicates - people asking about the same thing in different ways. That's precisely how closing questions as duplicates helps in searching - people search for X or Y, doesn't matter, they reach the correct place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why there is two identical bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408545/why-there-is-two-identical-bash)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are /bin and /sbin now symlinks in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242157/why-are-bin-and-sbin-now-symlinks-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dpkg` does not make any attempt to resolve `link`s, `bind`-mounts, or any other such 'duplicate view' of files/inodes/directories, even within the same filesystem.  It would be difficult (impossible?) to resolve all such cases especially in the general case (more than one filesystem, as many installs use).  It also likely hues closer to the Unix philosophy of "do one thing well".

On some systems (including recent Ubuntu's), `/bin` is a `symlink` to `/usr/bin`, meaning logic that "searches" (such as `which`) will see two copies, but logic using static ~manifests (such as `dpkg`) will see just the file(s) explicitly install.  Because this is a *directory* symlink, it's also transparent / not directly discoverable looking at the file entry itself on the underlying inode, one must examine all the parents.